# Is it possible to rotate UIAlertController (and Alert) in landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uialertcontroller

I am editing an app where I added a new UIViewController to configure a multiplayer game in one layout.

I have added two buttons for each player (top button, bot button). Each button generates an alert at  the screen (remember it is in landscape orientation ) but the problem is, player 2 do not see the alert rotated, I mean, the alert is supposed to be shown in his orientation, in front of me.

As there any way to do this? I want to rotate an Alert for the player 2  will  not see the information of the alert turned.

Here the alert code I have:

```
@IBAction func ShowAlert(){
let message = "Test"
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(action)

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a way to rotate an alert controller view, although it is not perfect. The controller tries to present based on the orientation and I found that attempting to transform it before it is presented is unsuccessful.

In order to not see "incorrect" orientation initially, you must set the alert to `hidden` and then make it visible once it is "presented".

```
let alert // setup

alert.view.hidden = true;
[self presentViewController:c animated:YES completion:^{
    alert.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
    alert.view.hidden = false;
}];
```

The only outstanding issue I have with this is that after the user interacts with the alert, it flashes back to the initial transformation (orientation dependent). I currently have not found a solution for this, but will update if I ever do.

---

Alternatively, using a custom "alert" would solve this problem as you would have more control over its view. This is probably the more reliable approach.

Comment: Have you maybe found solution for rotation at dismissal (flashing)?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution.
`presentViewController` with no animation to avoid flash when present the alert controller.

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:^{
    [alertController.view setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
 }];
```

then create a UIAlertController category named e.g. `UIAlertController+Orientation`, 
hide the view in `viewWillDisappear` to avoid flash back when dismiss the alert controller.

```
#import "UIAlertController+Orientation.h"

@implementation UIAlertController (Orientation)

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.view setHidden:YES];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: viewWillDisappear is not getting called. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of UIAlertController and in disappear hide view for Alert as below. and it won't flicker or rotate on User Interactions.

```
@MainActor open class CustomAlertView : UIAlertController {
    open override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        view.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

and Use it like below same as UIAlertController.

```
    let alert = CustomAlertView(title: "Rotate 180", message: "Please confirm Alert view is rotated 180 degree(landscape)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.isHidden = true;
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true) {
        alert.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(Double.pi / 2.0);
        alert.view.isHidden = false;
    }
```