# iOS mirrored Arabic in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using Xcode 7.3, iOS Deployment Target 8.0 , Base SDK 9.3.
Now I'm updating the deprecated APIs , one of them is the UIAlertView (deprecated) to the new API (UIAlertViewController).
but the new alert is mirroring Arabic language. it is supposed to be RTL (as in the old API), but now it is left to right .
I also noticed the problem when updating to Xcode9.2 . but it seems even in Xcode 7.3 it also occurs.
[image: mirrored]

Edited ( now it looks correct but when dismissing the view I can still see the incorrect view for 1 sec)

```
   alert.view.hidden = TRUE;

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{
      alert.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
      alert.view.hidden = false;

   }];
```

Comment: Most likely a transform is being done somewhere; something like `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)`.

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf thanks for the suggestion , it led me to this [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927652/is-it-possible-to-rotate-uialertcontroller-and-alert-in-landscape-orientation) but as the comments mentioned , when dismissing the alert it goes back left to right for 1 sec. so I have to work on that

Comment: You shouldn't need to apply that transform. @AhmedKhalaf's point is that somewhere that transform is likely being applied and it should be removed, not that you should add it. Is this a completely standard `UIAlertController`? How are you creating it?

Comment: @RobNapier yeah it is as the standard. But maybe the previous UIAlertView was customized somewhere. the thing is someone else worked on this app and they already moved on a along time ago, before I took over .In some code I can see the whole window is flipped when the language is in Arabic. so it should be already RTL .but it isin't . thanks man

Comment: When you say "the whole window is flipped" do you mean it's RTL, or do you mean it's mirrored? I'm suspecting someone has applied a transform either to the window or to the view or to the alert, and it needs to come out. A transform is not the way to achieve RTL.

Comment: The whole UIView is mirrored + some custom UI elements such as labels are specifically mirrored . yeah I'm seeing transform being used in classes that are inherited in other classes. self.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  but it is too early for me to make sense of where /how it is being used. Thank you @RobNapier

Comment: @Rima I kind of understand what is happening. I guess the whole views are mirrored to "mimic" RTL layout, then views with readable content (e.g. UILabel) are mirrored again to correctly show their content. This is a risky approach, but I understand the hurry that may have been behind that thinking. If you have enough time to rethink the way your project is implementing RTL, take a look at a less risky (but still not elegant) approach. https://ahmedk92.github.io/2017/12/15/Acheiving-Dynamic-Localisation-in-iOS.html

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf yeah you are absolutely right. thank you so much :) . I'm still learning and I'm pretty sure the UILabel etc are being customized somehow in code. As I tried to move the app to Xcode 9.2 without updating any API ,then saw this issue happening in the navigationitems as well. I just need more time to learn Objective-c  concepts to understand the architecture of this app. I will post something once I do .