# UITapGestureRecognizer not recognized with RTL View and Side Menu view

Tags: ios, swift

I have side menu , in case open i have UIView created programmatically to cover the main view, and by clicking on it using TapGeastureRecognizer the menu should closed and everything is working fine in Left to right English , but the Arabic (Right to Left) version has a problem:

TapGeastureRecognizer is not recognized on the main view but recognizing on the side menu view as mentioned in the picture.
[SideMenu Opened Image Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6kHe.png)

```
import UIKit

class ContainerVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuView: UIView!
    var sideMenuOpen = false
    let cover = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toggleSideMenu(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name("ToggleSideMenu"), object: nil)

    }
    func createCover(){
        self.cover.frame = CGRect(x: self.containerView.frame.origin.x, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.width, height: self.containerView.frame.height)
        self.cover.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: -1, alpha: 0.4)
        self.cover.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.closeMenu(sender:)))
        self.cover.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    @objc func toggleSideMenu(_ notification: NSNotification){
        if !sideMenuOpen {
            self.sideMenuOpen = true
            self.sideMenuConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.addSubview(cover)
        }else{
            self.sideMenuOpen = false
            self.sideMenuConstraint.constant = -240
            cover.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                self.createCover()
        })
    }

    @objc func closeMenu(sender: UIView){
        self.sideMenuOpen = false
        self.sideMenuConstraint.constant = -240
        cover.removeFromSuperview()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `cover` as a subview, it's added on top of all other subviews. Apple documentation on `addSubview(_:)`:

> ### Parameter: *view*
>
> The view to be added. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.

You need to rearrange your views each time you add the cover, e.x:

```
view.sendSubviewToBack(cover)
view.sendSubviewToBack(containerView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Salam,

I had a slightly similar issue please check this out

[iOS mirrored Arabic in Xcode 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202545/ios-mirrored-arabic-in-xcode-7-3)